# SqlEntityConnection and EF 6 Async

Tags: f#, entity-framework-6, type-providers

Is there any way to use the [SqlEntityConnection Type Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362322.aspx) with the async features introduced in Entity Framework 6? The type provider itself seems to work well enough with EF 6, but I'm not seeing any way to access any of the async methods. Am I missing something, or does anyone know if there are plans to add async support to the type provider?

Comment: If I reference the EntityFramework.dll, and open the System.Data.Entity namespace, I get all the Async extension methods for IQueryable. Unfortunately when I execute any async queries I get an InvalidOperationException with a message containing "The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable".

Comment: Confirmed that is issue exists for EF 6.1. It looks like this is an F# Tools team issue, not an Entity Framework team issue.

Comment: Issue has been cross posted: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/6d2450b2-c294-44d4-b75f-d5cec3730c24/type-provider-sqlentityconnection-and-ef-6-async?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: I've added a feature suggestion for Entity Framework: [Updating the F# SqlEntityConnection Type Provider for EF 6](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5707604-updating-the-f-sqlentityconnection-type-provider)